# I need help figuring out what kind of tree I have

Tags: identification, trees

So when I dug this tree up from the base of my Mahogany tree I assumed it was growing from one of the seeds and was a mahogany tree as well.  As you can tell it is not a mahogany tree at all but at the time it was a stick with two little leaves.  it has long kind of thin leaves with a red vein running down the center and smaller veins running out from it.  I just want to know if it is a tree or bush and what it is.  I really hope it's not poisonous since I have 2 little ones and a dog that will sample anything if you let them.  Any Help would be much appreciated[image].

Comment: What part of the world is the plant located in?  By any chance when you puncture or bend a leaf does white sap come out?

Comment: Yes, where you are ought to help. I have a strong suspicion, the leaves are of a member of the Magnoliaceae family. Do you have any Magnolias growing nearby? That could still not mean much, if the seed was dispersed by wind or a critter.

Comment: I immediately thought Plumeria, Would like to see more pics of stem,etc.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [sweetbay magnolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_virginiana) (Magnolia virginiana).

Comment: It might help others if you explain why you believe it is this (and increase the odds of some upvotes). I added a source for you and rephrased it a bit.